# Is there an optic which reflects RCP beam and transmits LCP beam, or vice versa?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, polarization, optical-materials

I'm currently looking for an optic which reflects the right circular polarized (RCP) beam and transmits the left circular polarized (LCP) beam, or vice versa. I prefer the incident angle of 0 deg but if not available, I don't mind other incident angles such as 45 deg(like beamsplitter). The wavelength I use is 532 nm.

Is there any commercial products available? I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: This is very hard if you want to do it in a single surface. What's wrong with sandwiching a polarizing beam splitter between quarter-wave plates?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping request, rather than a question about physics concepts